# AngulaJS add a class to parent for active radiobutton

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, radio-button

I'm curious how to add a class to the parent `div` for the `<input type="radio">` for the group of radio buttons?

The code is below and [JSFiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/6urevw2t/)

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="bd"> <input type="radio" ng-model="value" value="foo" ng-change='newValue(value)'></div>
        <div class="bd active"><input type="radio" ng-model="value" value="bar" ng-change='newValue(value)'></div>
            <div class="bd"><input type="radio" ng-model="value" value="baz" ng-change='newValue(value)'>    </div>
<hr> 

</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.value= 'foo';

    $scope.newValue = function(value) {
       console.log(value);
    }
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.bd {
    border:1px solid red;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
}
.active{
    border:1px solid green;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with ng-class directive:

```
<div  ng-class="{'active': value=='foo'}" ...>
```

Here is the fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/6urevw2t/2/

Hope it helps,

Regards